# Get name of updated document as variable

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to write a cloud function that listens to updates on all documents in a particular collection and does something with the one that has been updated. That means there should be a way to reference the document name as a variable, rather than explicitly. Right now I can send a notification for one specific document like so:

```
exports.onRiskUpdate = functions.firestore.document('users/45wfho9').onUpdate((_change: any) => {
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "Notification title",
            body: "Notification body",
        },
    };
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic("45wfho9", payload);
});
```

I'd like to be able to do that for any user, not just the one with id 45wfho9

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use wildcards:

```
exports.onRiskUpdate = functions.firestore.document('users/{userId}').onUpdate((change, context) => {
    const userId = context.params.userId;
    const payload = {
        notification: {
            title: "Notification title",
            body: "Notification body",
        },
    };
    return admin.messaging().sendToTopic(userId, payload);
});
```

This will listen for updates in all documents in the 'users' collection, you can then use `context.params.userId` to get the document id.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events#wildcards-parameters

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/extend-with-functions#trigger_a_function_when_a_document_is_updated

Comment: Thanks! Might you replace the string "45wfho9" in the return statement with the appropriate code?